# How much more often is a definite article used with a noun than an indefinite article in the English language?

Tags: english, frequency, articles, indefinite-article

I'd be happy if I could get an overall answer to this question, but if someone is also capable of breaking this down by

**single vs. plural nouns

nouns as subject vs. nouns as direct objects

nouns as subject vs. nouns as indirect objects**

I'm not all that concerned about the corpora that would be used for this, but preferably it would be fairly representative of average, modern-day English.

Comment: You're just looking for numbers, then? Shorn of context, they would be very unreliable. Especially since it's **hard** to tell subjects and objects apart automatically; what about alternations and transformations and non-nominal subjects and objects?

Comment: @jlawler  I appreciate your commitment to concerns about providing a quality answer, but I really was just looking for generalities.  The need to consider all that you've mentioned in your comment isn't something I am seeking at the moment, but down the road there may be, and I hope to remember some of the concerns you presented in your comment.  Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Leipzig Wortschatz Portal](https://corpora.uni-leipzig.de/en/res?corpusId=eng_news_2016&word=the) is a good place to get answers for this kind of questions. The definite article is more than twice as frequent as the indefinite one (158M vs 67M + 10M).

Unfortunately, no further breakdown is in there, they just count wordforms, but on very large corpora.

Comment: Exactly the type of answer I was looking for.  Thank you!